# Place the same dojo datagrid in multiple places

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is it possible to place the same dojo data grid twice (or even more) on the same page? I have a Tab container and I need to show the grid inside at least two of the tabs. Is it as easy as modifying `grid.placeAt("gridDiv");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much as you can only put one DOM node in one place at the same time, you can only put one widget in one place at the same time. If you need multiple grids that are the same, you’ll need to create multiple instances of the grid.